# Why does my JS for-if loop end up with the wrong result?

Tags: javascript

I have an -actually- quiet simple for-if loop set up. But for whatever reason it ends up with the wrong result. I tried to debug  with dozens of console.logs but can't find the bug.

**The loop:**

```
 var bestTrade = 0
 for (var i = 0; i < tradesTotal; i++) {
    orderProfit = trades[i].fields.orderProfit
    orderType = trades[i].fields.orderType
    console.log('orderProfit: ' + orderProfit + ' OrderType ' + orderType + 'latest bestTrade ' + bestTrade)
    if (orderProfit > 0 && orderProfit > bestTrade && orderType !== 6) {
        bestTrade = orderProfit
    } else {}
 }
console.log(bestTrade)
```

The loop iterates over a JSON file which contains 27 objects. Each object contains `trades[i].fields.orderProfit` and I want to assign the largest profit to the variable `bestTrade`. Also objects containing the `orderType = 6`  shouldn't be included.

**Console.log output** which clearly shows the correct number of iterations and the correct profits/orderTypes, but the result is wrong which should be `5567.09` and not `810.92`:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try converting the `orderProfit`  to `Number`. From the result it looks as though orderProfit is string. `'810.92' > '5567.09'` returns true.

```
 var bestTrade = 0
 for (var i = 0; i < tradesTotal; i++) {
    orderProfit = Number( trades[i].fields.orderProfit );
    orderType = trades[i].fields.orderType
    console.log('orderProfit: ' + orderProfit + ' OrderType ' + orderType + 'latest bestTrade ' + bestTrade)
    if (orderProfit > 0 && orderProfit > bestTrade && orderType !== 6) {
        bestTrade = orderProfit
    } else {}
 }
console.log(bestTrade)
```